# Is there online tool to check if bitcoin transaction is bip-125-replaceable

Tags: bitcoind, bip-125-replaceable

bitcoind json-rpc can do it, I think I saw this on blockchain.info but I don't see it now.

Answer (score 2):

`getmempoolentry` does it. However this is restricted to txes currently in mempool.

Comment: well, I was hoping there is online tool, where I can paste tx hash and see if my client who is sending coins to me actually can do bump fee, before asking him to do so